# how to get values of prefix id's in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to get prefix id values and check i.e. id defined or not, and how to store a value in variable.

```
calculate_grand_total();
}

function calculate_grand_total() {
  var rowcount = $("#hidden_rowcount").val();
  var grand_total = parseFloat(0);
  for (i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
    grand_total += parseFloat($("#gtl_" + i).val());
  }
  $("#totalamt").html(grand_total);

}
```

If one of the id is missing that time it should not printing

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm struggling to understand your question. What exactly do you mean by *prefix id values*?

Comment: `var grand_total=parseFloat(0);` makes no sense,

Comment: So add a check to see if it exists before adding it

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use data?

```
<div id="hidden_rowcount" data-id="2">
```

Then

```
var hidd_row_id = $("#hidden_rowcount").data("id");
console.log(hidd_row_id);
```